# Unsure how to work with mov (a,b,c),d

Tags: assembly

What is mov doing here?

```
mov(%ebx,%eax,4),%eax
```

I've seen mov used to transfer a value from one function to another, but I'm not sure how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `segment:displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)` [in AT&T syntax is equivalent to] `segment:[base register + displacement + offset register * scalar multiplier]` in Intel syntax. ([source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Address_operand_syntax))

So `mov(%ebx,%eax,4),%eax` is equivalent to `mov eax, [ebx + eax*4]`. That is, form an address by `ebx + eax*4` and load a doubleword from that address into `eax`.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply!!